# Tic-Tac-Toe Print the Path of Best Move in Game Tree Search?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am working on the alpha-beta pruning algorithm with Tic-Tac-Toe game (3x3). Currently for any given instance of the 3x3 grid, I was able to figure out the best case:

```
public Best chooseAlphaBetaMove(int whosMov, int alpha, int beta) {

    Best reply = new Best();  
    Best myBest = new Best();

    if ((scoreGrid()==COMPUTER_WIN) || (scoreGrid()==OPPONENT_WIN) || 
                                       (scoreGrid()==GAME_DRAW)) {
        int score = scoreGrid();
        return new Best(score,-3,-3,count);
    }

    if (whosMov==COMPUTER_MOVE) {
        myBest.score = alpha;
    } else {
        myBest.score = beta;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        if (layOut[i][j]==0) {
            moveGrid(whosMov,i,j);
            reply = chooseAlphaBetaMove(-whosMov,alpha,beta); 
            unmoveGrid(i,j);

            if ((whosMov==COMPUTER_MOVE)&&(reply.score>myBest.score)) {
                myBest.score = reply.score;
                alpha = reply.score;
                myBest.row = i;
                myBest.column = j;
            }

            if  ((whosMov==OPPONENT_MOVE)&&(reply.score<myBest.score)) {
                myBest.score = reply.score;
                beta = reply.score;
                myBest.row = i;
                myBest.column = j;
            }
            if (beta <= alpha) return myBest;
        }
    }
    }

        return myBest;
}
```

Where the Best structure is:

```
public class Best {

    public int score;
    public int row;
    public int column;
    public int count
}
```

Given an initial grid and who will move next, I can know the best score and the best position for this next player to go. However, I can't figure out how to print the whole path for this best move. (Note - I don't want the whole search path. I only want to print out the single search path starting from this best move till the leaf). Any thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you go recursively down each path, you need to keep track of it, probably by passing a reference to a List/Stack into each `chooseAlphaBetaMove` call. When you find a better path than the current best path, you take a copy of the current path, and store it as the "best path so far". Once you have finished, you can then print out the best path.

Comment: thanks. Maybe I can keep a list of moves (i,j) to each myBest object? Then when I get the best myBest, I can go back to print out all the (i,j) of this myBest? I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to keep track of the best moves from your search. My suggestion is to keep a data structure that holds the list of best moves. A `Stack` seems like the most appropriate data structure for this situation. On each recursive call, push the first move to the stack (since this is the best move so far). When a better move is found, pop the stack and push the new one. After your alpha-beta pruning algorithm finishes, simply pop the stack and print each move. This will give the sequence of "best" moves to the end of the game.

Comment: This sounds right - but I can't find a good way to identify the myBest at each level. If I choose to add myBest to the stack each time I get a new myBest then that would be too many... In each level there could be multiple myBests, like we start from score of -1, then find score of 0 (first myBest), then find 1 (second myBest)...

Comment: @user1660652 The current "best" should be at the top of the stack. If you find a better "best", then pop the stack before you push the new one on.

Answer (score 1):

http://xkcd.com/832/ is an effective way to visualize a TTT tree

Comment: thanks - but this looks way more complex than what I intend to try.